# Spring applicationContext not loading in a POJO

Tags: spring, classpath, applicationcontext

My applicationContext is placed at path:src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\conf\applicationContext.xml

When I build this web application.I can see that conf folder is placed at {projectname.war}\WEB-INF\conf\applicationContext.xml.And Application works fine.

Now I happened to write a class with public static void main where I am trying to load applicationCOntext using below:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("../conf/applicationContext.xml");
```

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/conf/applicationContext.xml");
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
 none of above seems to be working.
error is listed below:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [../conf/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist.

Can someone point what wrong I am doing ?

Comment: Why are you writing a class with a main method in a web application? `/WEB-INF` isn't part of the class path so trying to load it from the class path isn't going to work. Prefix with `file:` and then, depending on the location of your class, it might load.

Comment: @M.Deinum was just trying to test some method in a java class in the src java folder.When I needed some beans I tried to load appContext which threw this error.

Comment: Why aren't you simply writing a jUnit test instead of a executable class? Saves you writing a lot of plumping and you can use springs resource loading and testing to make things easier.

Comment: that is what I am doing now.thanks M.